# How to correctly add Func to Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two blocks of code. I was wondering if they equivalent

```
properties = type.GetProperties()
                 .Where(IsNeverSerializedProperty)
                 .ToArray();

private static bool IsNeverSerializedProperty(PropertyInfo p)
{
        return p.Name.Contains("Password") || 
               p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute), false).Any();
}
```

Is it equivalent to the following code?

```
properties = type.GetProperties()
                 .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Password"))
                 .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute), true).Any()))
                 .ToArray();
```

If they are not equivalent, where I make a mistake?

Comment: They are not equal, as you provide different params to `GetCustomAttributes`. However why don´t you simply try it out in the debugger and see yourself if they are?

Comment: Assuming the `x` on line 3 of the second example is just a typo, they are still not equivalent: The second one filters all properties whose name contains "Password" _and_ that have `EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute`. The first one filters properties for which _either_ of these conditions is true.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to put the predicates of both Where methods into one Where Method: .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(...) && p.GetCustomerAttributes(...),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing the code to its basic form, your first snippet is of the form

```
list.Where(p => NameContainsPassword(p) || HasEncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute(p))
```

where I inlined your `IsNeverSerializedProperty` function.

The second function is of the form

```
list
  .Where(p => NameContainsPassword(p))
  .Where(p => HasEncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute(p))
```

which first filters all items for which `NameContainsPassword(p)` holds and then *from that* filters all items for which `HasEncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute` holds, hence this is equivalent to

```
list.Where(p => NameContainsPassword(p) && HasEncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute(p))
```

Note that the logical operator is different (`||` vs `&&`).

Answer (score 2):

They're not equivalent.

`IsNeverSerializedProperty` checks if a property name contains "Password" **OR** has the attribute `EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute` whereas the second query checks if property name contains "Password" **AND** property has the `EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute`.

Comment: So I need to add `&&` instead of `||` in `IsNeverSerializedProperty ` ?

Comment: Yes, that should do it.